# What does a Void Resonator do?

Tags: kittens-game

The description for this Void Space building, in Kittens Game, is:

> Every Void Resonator will improve Order of the Void effect by 10%.
>   Will trigger OotV on a time skips.

What is the Order of the Void effect that's being talked about here? Would someone please explain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Order of the Void](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=Metaphysics#Order_of_the_Void) is a Metaphysics perk that acts as an extra source of faith.  You get a percentage of your regular faith income that is automatically "praised" and sent to your Order of the Sun faith pool.

The Void Resonator acts as a buff to time mechanics related to faith income.  Normally when you shatter a time crystal and skip a year, the only resource you would gain for your trouble is your yearly antimatter.  Resource Retrieval buildings would allow you to get a portion of your other resource income for that year.  Void Resonator acts on the same principle, granting you a portion of that automatically praised faith income whenever you skip a year.

Void Resonators would be extremely helpful if, say, you were skipping a whole lot of years to build up a particular resource, and also wanted to build up all your faith bonuses to reach the higher Transcend levels.

Answer (score 1):

Order of the void is a buff you can buy with paragorn via [Metaphysics](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=Metaphysics#Order_of_the_Void).
It increases your faith generation by priests and apocrypha.

```
Order of the Void

Cost    Paragon 75
Effects Every priest will now give a minor bonus to faith accumulation.
Note: you get a new bonus faith income (10% of your regular faith income)
that is automatically praised at one quarter of your apocrypha bonus
```